# Unity 2D - Awry "jumping"

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I have some problems with jumps in my 2d-game. I have tried

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 200));  
// and
rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, 10f);
```

But my character doesn't jump straight up, but up-and-left. He is  jumping from horizontal area. What could it be?

UPDATE.
a little bit more code:

```
void Update() 
    {
       if (Input.GetKeyDown("w")) 
        {
          rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 200));
          //or rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, 10f);
          //or rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * 10);
        }
    }
```

I have tried FixedUpdate() - its the same problem. He just jumping to the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 jumpForce;

void Awake()
{
 jumpForce = new Vector3(0, y); //Put your desired jump force for y
}

void Update() 
{
   if (Input.GetKeyDown("w")) 
    {         
     _rigidBody2D.velocity += jumpForce;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.